# Excel - Hide "count of" 1 in Pivot Chart

Tags: excel

I know this is something very simple, but I can't remember how I completed this the last time. I have a pivot table and an associated pivot chart. The table/chart has an axis field that counts the number of entries from a certain column. I'd like to filter out single entries so they're not displayed in my pivot chart. I'm able to add a filter to the pivot table and only have it show values that are greater than 1, but these changes aren't reflected in the chart. Can anyone help me out? I know this is a quick fix, but for some reason can't figure it out. Thanks.